# Load CreateJS canvas from json data

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, createjs

I use create.js library and want to load canvas objects from json data and import canvas object to json.
Previously I used fabric.js and there was function:

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData, function() {});
```

and

to import canvas to JSON data `canvas.toJSON()` or `canvas.toDatalessJson()`,

so I'm interested if this is possible in create.js too?

if yes how i can do it?

Comment: There is currently no support for this in EaselJS.